# Why can't I call the function inside a certain class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm currently having a project that opens a Main Window and then opens the second window upon clicking a button. The Main window class is fine and is able to call the functions inside it while the second window can still show it's UI but can't call it's functions(button in the second window is not calling the function it's supposed to call). Is there something I missed?

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self, dlg):
        self.dlg = dlg
        dlg.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)

        dlg.systemBase.setText(make_prefix(Sbase)+"VA")

        dlg.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.Calc)
        dlg.comboBox.addItem(str(380.00/1e3))
        dlg.comboBox.addItem(str(400.00/1e3))
        dlg.comboBox.addItem(str(220.00/1e3))


        dlg.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText("Accepts 1-10")
        dlg.lineEdit_3.setValidator(QIntValidator(1,10))
        dlg.lineEdit_3.textChanged.connect(self.disableButton)


        dlg.comboBox_2.addItem("Single Phase")
        dlg.comboBox_2.addItem("3 Phase")

        dlg.pushButton_3.setDisabled(True)
        dlg.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.selectPhase)
        dlg.lineEdit_3.setFocus()
        dlg.lineEdit_3.returnPressed.connect(self.selectPhase)
        dlg.show()
        app.exec()

    def Calc(self):
        Vbase=float(self.dlg.comboBox.currentText())
        currentBase = ((Sbase)/ (math.sqrt(3) * (Vbase*1e3)))
        dlg.currentBase.setText(str(make_prefix(currentBase))+"A")
        baseImpedance = (((Vbase*1e3)*(Vbase*1e3)) / (Sbase))
        dlg.baseImpedance.setText(str(make_prefix(baseImpedance))+" p.u.")


    def selectPhase(self):
        Nbus = dlg.lineEdit_3.text()
        if Nbus == "1":
            self.SW = uic.loadUi("try1.ui")
            SecondWindow(self.SW) #calling the second window
        else:
            print("try again")


        print(int(Nbus))
        if self.dlg.comboBox_2.currentText() == "Single Phase":
            print("u selected single phase")

        else:
            print("u selected 3 phase")


    def disableButton(self):
        if len(self.dlg.lineEdit_3.text()) > 0:
            dlg.pushButton_3.setDisabled(False)
        else:
            dlg.pushButton_3.setDisabled(True)


class SecondWindow():
    def __init__(self, SW):
        self.SW = SW

        #Button
        SW.pushButton.setText("Calculate")
        SW.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tst) #nothing happens in clicking the button. 
        SW.show()
    def tst(self): 
        print("testing")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    dlg=uic.loadUi("try.ui")
    MainWindow(dlg)
```

I expect to print the string inside the tst() function from SecondWindow class.

Comment: check the Condition before calling the SecondWindow. maybe SecondWindow is not called at all in the MainWindow class

Comment: Please publish the files `try.ui` and `try1.ui`

Comment: @basilisk It is called in the selectPhase function in MainWindow class. The SecondWindow also displays it's UI so i think it is definitely called.

Comment: Maybe bind your second window back to the original SW? `self.SW = SecondWindow(self.SW)`? And perhaps in the `__init__` for `SecondWindow` do `self.SW.pushButton.setText() ...` Because ultimately your `tst` function is bound to the `SecondWindow` object but `SW` is not a `SecondWindow` object

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy Thank you! This solved the problem.

Comment: np. I actually edited my answer above haha. Just thought you should also update the `__init__` for the second object